# Why am I experiencing these problems using IE8?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a site that looks great in all of the browsers except in Internet Explorer. I am currently testing on Internet Explorer 8. I managed to work out some things using a conditional stylesheet(ie.css), but there are a few problems I just simply cannot figure out. I am open to any suggestions involving either CSS or jQuery.

Here is a link to the Site: [Test Page](http://linkremoved.com)

These are the problems I am currently experiencing:

1. **Button disappears on Hover**
   When you hover over the 'Resources' button, it adds a dropdown menu(using the [WordPress Dropdown Menu Widget Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dropdown-menu-widget/)). When you hover over one of the sub menu anchors, the parent button completely disappears. How can I force the parent button to stay visible when the child button is hovered over?
2. **Main Container won't center on page**
   The main content area(#content_area) is not centering on the page. I have a set width and margin: 0 auto is also defined, but the content area is still not centering on the page. I have tried many different approaches to fix this, but still no luck.

   I also need to center the bottom area(#bottom_area) but I imagine it would just be using the same strategy as for the main content area.

   Any ideas on how I can get them centered?
3. **Mystery margin on right side of page**
   On the right edge of the page is a margin of about 10px that I can't figure out where it is coming from. How can I remove that?

Comment: Internet Explorer!, a hell nightmare for WebDevelopers

Comment: Make `body` css . `body { width:960px; margin:0 auto; }`. well this might work to align in center

Comment: Thx Rafee! That removed the mystery margin on the right side of the page. It still looks like there is a 1 or 2 pixel margin-right there, although I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you have invalid html. First move the `<link ...>`-tag before the `<DOCTYPE ... />` into the `<head>`. I think some problems are solved then. E.g. the css `color: inherit;` sometimes it doesn't work if the IE can't analyze the doctype.

=== UPDATE ===

After the cahnges the html should be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Lybeck Murphy, LLP - Lawyers</title>
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='http://lybeckmurphy.com/test/wp-content/themes/mtt/custom_post_type.css' />
...
```

Watch your 'page source', after your first changes it looks like:

```
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='http://lybeckmurphy.com/test/wp-content/themes/mtt/custom_post_type.css' /><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Lybeck Murphy, LLP - Lawyers</title>
...
```

Comment: Yep. IE goes into QURIKS mode because invalid structure. Sometimes the problem isn't IE, but just bad coding ;-)

Comment: Yes!, i agree sometimes.. I have learnt that some our modern browser like chrome rectifies it and make it a valid structure, thats the reason.. some page make feel good in chrome but where as in mozilla it works on the structure of the page.. where as Internet Explorer even creator doest have any clue to that defaults sometime..

Comment: I moved the doctype below the link tags and it doesn't seem to solve anything. Can you please take a look and let me know if there is something I didn't do correctly?

Comment: The onliest difference I can see in your html is that the doctype is removed. The link is still before the head. Add the doctype again and move only the link into the head.

Comment: You were right! I moved the files the way you recommended and it worked wonderfully! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I notice you don't have a doctype specified. This probably won't solve all of your problems, but some of IE's most frustrating CSS issues can be alleviated with the simple inclusion of the appropriate doctype. Welcome to the world of [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Comment: I do have a doctype specified. It is <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">. scessor recommended I move it below the link tags so I moved it to the end of the <head> tag, but it doesn't seem to solving anything. Am I using the correct doctype?

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Because you have HTML preceding the doctype, quirks mode is triggered in IE, which means that it's going to try to render the page for compatibility with older browsers (i.e: not standards-compliant or consistent with modern browsers). Your doctype should be the first line in your HTML document (although server-side code like PHP can still precede it). You can use IE9's F12 developer tools to see which rendering mode is being triggered by default, as well as emulate the rendering modes of IE8 and IE7, which you may find useful as you test.

Answer (score 0):

Copy following tag in the <head> tag as first tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

It should resolve your issues.

Comment: I added it in and it didn't seem to change anything. What is it supposed to fix?

Comment: Adding this tag forces the IE8 rendering engine to produce output exactly like IE7. Thus your application will exactly look like IE7, with Compatibility View button hidden.